# 'NoneType' object is not iterable when trying to loop over GA API result

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

My final goal is to export in csv the top 500 pages from multiple property within the same account. I have 8 property so I want 8 csv at the end.

Before getting to that, I would like to be able to build multiple lists containing the 500 pages urls for each property.

Since I'm new to python I'm building my script step-by-step.

First I'm building a list of profile ID :

```
profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
      accountId='XXXXX',
      webPropertyId='UA-XXXXXXX-XX').execute()

  for profile in profiles.get('items', []):
    list.append(profile.get('id'))
```

Second I'm iterating over this list to get the top 500 pages for each profiles :

```
  for item in list:
    test = service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + item,
      start_date='1daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      metrics='ga:sessions',
      dimensions='ga:pagePath',
      sort='-ga:sessions',
      filters='ga:sessions>500').execute()
```

Third (It is where things get complicated) I want to loop over the result of the `test` variable (?) and add to a new array each urls pages :

```
for row in test.get('rows'):
  rawdata.append(row)
```

When executing the script at this stage I have the following error :

```
  File "test.py", line 71, in get_first_profile_id
    for row in test.get('rows'):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Here is the all code:

```
  profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
      accountId='5140486',
      webPropertyId='UA-5140486-16').execute()

  for profile in profiles.get('items', []):
    list.append(profile.get('id'))

  for item in list:
    test = service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + item,
      start_date='1daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      metrics='ga:sessions',
      dimensions='ga:pagePath',
      sort='-ga:sessions',
      filters='ga:sessions>500').execute()

    for row in test.get('rows'):
      rawdata.append(row)
```

I hope my goal is clear. thanks for helping !

Comment: Are you sure that test['rows'] exists? If not, just add `if 'rows' in test` before the last for-loop and check your indentation.

Comment: Or use `test.get('rows', [])` like in the earlier loop on `profiles.get('items', [])`. It might also make sense to use the `list.extend` method instead of doing a bunch of `append` calls in a loop. (Also, it's a very bad idea to have a variable named `list`.)

Comment: @Blckknght It's working with `test.get('rows', [])`. Can you write a proper answer about this ? I don't understand why. I've also rename my variable `list`, you are totally right. thanks ! You can also tell me more about the `list.extend` thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For at least one of the values you're running on, the data you load as `test` doesn't have a `rows` key. When you call `test.get('rows')` for that item, it returns `None` (since you don't give it a different default value). That leads to your exception when you try to iterate over the rows.

You can avoid the exception by using `test.get('rows', [])` (like you are doing above to the `items` from `profiles`). You can also streamline things a bit by using `list.extend` instead of looping and calling `append` repeatedly:

```
profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
    accountId='XXXXX',
    webPropertyId='UA-XXXXXXX-XX').execute()

my_list.extend(profile.get('id') for profile in profiles.get('items', [])) # use extend

for item in my_list:  # it's a really bad idea to have a variable named list, so I renamed it
    test = service.data().ga().get(
        ids='ga:' + item,
        start_date='1daysAgo',
        end_date='today',
        metrics='ga:sessions',
        dimensions='ga:pagePath',
        sort='-ga:sessions',
        filters='ga:sessions>500').execute()

    rawdata.extend(test.get('rows', []))   # here too
```

Note that this will silently ignore missing data. That could be fine if having missing data is an ordinary thing. However, if it's unusual, you might want want to treat it as an error. An easy way to do that would be to use `test['rows']` and catch a `KeyError` wherever you want to handle the issue.